# How to compile compose 1.1.1 with Kotlin 1.6.20

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've got an error like this while building my project:

`e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.20 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck but don't say I didn't warn you!).`

I'm using the newest IntelliJ Pro, and the newest Kotlin version.

How can I get the project to compile?

Comment: `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck`? Says it in the error…

Comment: @BoristheSpider it said "don't say I didn't warn you!" So it may cause bugs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

for kotlin version 1.6.20 you need to add this line in your build.gradle

```
 composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0-alpha08'
}
```

Refer to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) by google to find out more about kotlin compatibility to different compose versions

Comment: Hi Felix Kariuki, thanks for the information shared, particularly the documentation link shared helps keep it updated directly from the current version compatibility. Thanks again, it helped fixing the issue.

Comment: @Simmam I am happy to have been of help

Answer (score 6):

You need to use kotlin version 1.6.10 to compile project with this version of compose. In next releases may be thay add new version of kotlin support.
Change your gradle/maven properties to solve this problem.

In Gradle change:

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
```

to:

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
```

Or you can add compiler args (But there may be problems):

```
"-P", "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you can see compose and kotlin version mapping
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

```
1.2.0-alpha08 ->1.6.20
1.1.0-rc02 -1.2.0-alpha07 ->1.6.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the compatibility table posted by user2851150 above,https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin, it works for me setting in build.gradle (module) :

```
android{
 ...
  composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    kotlinCompilerVersion '1.6.10'
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: This is proper answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow 2 steps for this,

1. go to your build.gradle(project) and there change your kotlin version for kotlin-gradle-plugin

```
   ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
   //....
   dependencies {
       classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   }
}
```

2. change your kotlin version for plugins -

```
plugins {
    ...
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another update to this answer, since they still have not fixed this for Chipmunk. I left in comments what was causing the issue, so you may have to update again with new versions.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        //compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'  -> causes problems
        compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha08'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    //id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false -> causes problems
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.20' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the build.gradle in project level and change the kotlin version to mapped the required and compatible version